# Connect between turtles and their origin patches

Tags: netlogo

I want to ask how can I connect between the turtles and their origin patch
I create the turtles by using

```
sprout-turtles 2 ;; so their origin is not (0 0)
```

I want to have an action only happen when they are in their origin patch otherwise another action will happen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `turtles-own` variable. `origin` would be a name for it. When the turtles are created, you just need to have them set that variable to `patch-here`:

```
set origin patch-here
```

Then, you can check if they're at their origin patch with: `patch-here = origin`.